# What are the proper namespace and assemblies for RawRabbit?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, messaging, rawrabbit

Trying to use RawRabbit. I installed RawRabbit and RawRabbit.Next using PM The documentation suggests the following:

```
var raw = BusClientFactory.CreateDefault();
```

However none of the namespace make it compilable. Which assembly should be installed?

Answer (score 0):

After installing latest `RawRabbit` and `RawRabbit.vNext` packages (both are of version `1.10.3.0`) I was able to use `BusClientFactory` class from `RawRabbit.vNext` namespace.

So, be sure that:

- Packages installed successfully
- You've added `using RawRabbit.vNext;`